# Is there a sequence of strings where there is always an element between any two other elements?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can I define a way of sorting strings such that for any two strings X and Z, I can find another one Y such that X < Y < Z ?

This is clearly not the case for alphanumeric sorting: there is no string between "4a" and "4a0".

But it's not obvious to me whether there might be a sequence definition that takes advantage of the fact that strings can be infinitely long, where you could always find a string between two others.

I haven't been able to do so, but I lack the formal understanding to be able to decide whether this is fundamentally not possible.

Comment: Well, in theory, sure.   You could map a countable set to the rationals, and the rationals are dense.  Use the cantor diagonalization function to turn each string into a rational.   It'd be computationally ugly though, I don't know if there's a practical way of doing it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just construct a bijection between the set of strings and and the set of rational numbers. Then pull back the order on $\mathbb Q$ on the strings.

You probably don't need a bijection on $\mathbb Q$, you just need a function $f: S \to \mathbb R$ which has dense image.

For example think about each character being a number starting at 0. Thus, any strong becomes $a_1.. a_n$ where each $a_i \in \{ 0, 1, 2, ..,35 \}$.

Now define $f(a_1.. a_n)=2^{a_1}3^{-a_2}5^{a_3} ... p_n^{(-1)^{n+1}a_n}$ where $p_n$ is the $n$ th prime number.

Define $a_1.. a_n < b_1...b_k$ if and only if $f(a_1..a_n) < f(b_1...b_k)$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not clear how this proves formally that there is such an f() for a given alphabet. (My disadvantage is I don't know what a bijection is and its properties, sorry!) Unless I'm mistaken, the given f() doesn't work.   Take a1..an = "0" (n=1) and b1..bk = "00" (k=2).   f(a1..an) = 2^0 = 1.   f(b1..bk)=2^0*3^-0 = 1.   Since two strings have the same f(), we can't find a string between them using this formula.   Maybe the mapping of ai is wrong, and a1 should be 1 rather than 0?   But still - how do we _know_ that this formula works after that correction (or even that one exists at all)?

Comment: @GreenAsJade A bijection is a mapping between two sets that takes every element in the first set and maps it onto every element in the second. For instance, given the set ${1, 2, 3}$ and the set ${c, b, a}$, one bijection would be ${(1, a), (2, c), (3, b)}$. If there is a bijection between two sets then they have equal size (even if that size is one of the infinities). Also, in case you were unaware, "dense" refers to the property of a set that for any elements X and Z, you can find another one Y such that X < Y < Z (for some definition of <).

Comment: @GreenAsJade I think you are right about not differentiating between 0 and 00, but this is easily fixed by replacing $a_i$ by $a_i+1$. If you start at 1 instead of 0, the fact that the prime factorization of integers is unique tells you that $f$ diferentiate between strings. To prove that this has the desired property requires some work, but can be proved...

Answer (score 4):

To address this question we first need to have a precise definition of what a "string" is.

The usual formalization is that we have an "alphabet" containing some finite number of symbols. The "alphabet" is not necessarily just letters of a language; for example, you could have an alphabet of $36$ symbols ($26$ letters and $10$ numeric digits) or an alphabet of
$1000$ symbols.  A "string" is a sequence of these symbols, possibly with repetition.
A "string" can be as long as we want, so given any string there is always a longer one.
We *could* include strings of infinite length in our model, but (at least for now)
let's consider only strings of finite length.

Now observe that if you take the alphabet consisting of the ten decimal digits 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9, make strings over this alphabet, and then write
a decimal point before the first symbol of each of these strings, we have all the
terminating decimal fractions in the interval $[0,1).$

Now, if this set were strictly ordered by numeric value, we'd be almost done.
Unfortunately, these terminating decimal fractions include many that end with
one or more zeros, and these are numerically equal to decimals with fewer digits.

So for any terminating decimal with trailing zeros, count the number of trailing zeros
and write that number *before* the decimal point. For example, in this way
the string "123000" corresponds to the number $3.123.$ 
Use this as a rule to define a mapping $f$ from strings over the decimal digits
to rational numbers. Every string over this alphabet is
mapped to a unique number (different from any other string).
Now if $X$ and $Y$ are any two strings over this alphabet, say that
$X < Y$ if $f(X) < f(Y).$

Now observe that any decimal number $x$ with a finite number of digits
is equal to $f(X)$ for some string $X$ of decimal digits;
specifically, $X$ consists of all the digits of $x$ after the decimal point
(excluding any trailing zeros), followed by $\lfloor x \rfloor$ zeros.

Between any two terminating decimal numbers there is another terminating decimal number.
Therefore, for any strings $X$ and $Z$ such that $X < Z,$ 
there is a terminating decimal number $y$ such that $f(X) < y < f(Z).$
Construct the string $Y$ such that $f(Y) = y,$ and we have $X < Y < Z.$

Any other alphabet can be handled in a similar way. For an alphabet of $N$ symbols,
give each symbol a unique value in the range $0$ to $N-1,$ and define the ordering
of strings as we did for the ten decimal digits, but using a base-$N$ representation
instead of base $10$ if $N \neq 10.$

There are some slight complications if we allow infinitely long strings.

By the way, what if we don't explicitly stipulate that our alphabet has a
finite number of symbols? Finite alphabets are the norm for theory-of-computing
exercises (or at least they were when I studied that field), and this makes sense
if we imagine that each symbol must be written in a fixed number of bits of memory
in a computer, such as $8$-bit ANSI strings.
But there are encodings that allow different "characters" to be encoded in different
numbers of bits; for example, Unicode has several $8$-bit characters, then a larger
number of $16$-bit characters, and $24$-bit characters as well. We could define
an "infinitely-extended Unicode" encoding that repeated this pattern to simply 
increase the size of the next group of characters by $8$ bits, indefinitely.
And we could then define the order of the characters of this alphabet so that
there is always an $8n+8$-bit character that comes lexically before any
character of $8n$ or fewer bits. Using such an alphabet, there *would* be
a string that comes lexically between "4a" and "4a0", and other strings that
come lexically between any two other strings we might choose as counterexamples.

But infinite strings and infinite alphabets are a digression. Finite strings over
finite alphabets are interesting enough for the purpose of this question.

Comment: Thanks, I got a lot out of this answer.  I agree that infinites can be excluded (even though I introduced them - needlessly - in the question).   It appears to me that "by inspection", the f() that you have described works.   I'm curious how we _know_ that it works?   How do we know that every string produces a unique f(x), and (important to me, though not explicitly part of the question) that given a value of f(x), we can find the corresponding unique string?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - very easily too. For simplicity, assume we only have the letters $0$ and $1$ (but any number of letters will work just fine - it'll just be a different base system). We could interpret any string as a number, in base $2$ between $0$ and $1$ - like, the string "0110" becomes the number $.0110_2=\frac{3}{8}$. However, we have an issue with trailing zeros, since the strings "011" and "0110" and "01100" would all be considered equal. To remedy this, we can divide strings into various distinct classes, based on how many zeros they have and, if strings belong to different classes, we use the following rule:

- If string $A$ has more trailing zeros than string $B$, let $A>B$. (e.g. "0100" > "10" since the first has two trailing zeros. Similarly, "0100" > "010" - which avoids the fact that $.0100_2=.010_2$)

Then, we need to define the order within each class. Naively, we would just compare binary representations, with a decimal point at the start. However, this would mean that $1$ is the greatest binary representation obtainable in each class, and $0$ is the least (as pointed out in a comment) - which is a problem, since then our order has adjacent elements (e.g. the $1$ of a given class and the $0$ of the next greater class). Thus, we consider that a string $A$ should be associated with the the bit string in binary, with the decimal place before the first $0$ - so "11001" becomes $11.001_2$, for instance. Then, if $A$ has a greater associated number than $B$, we say $A>B$. There can be no maximum element in each class, since $A$ is always less than $A$ with a "1" prepended.

Then, we can easily construct a string between any $A$ and $B$. In particular, suppose $A>B$ and $A$ has more trailing zeros. Then $B$ with a "1" prepended is greater than $B$ and less than $A$. If they have equally many trailing zeros, we just choose some binary number (with integer part $2^{k}-1$ for some $k$ - numbers like $10_2$ aren't representable) between them and write it with equally many trailing zeros.

Comment: Let $A$ be "$1$" and let $B$ be "$10$". What string is between them? (I wish I had an answer to that. I was going to offer an ordering rule similar to yours but stumbled at this point.)

Comment: @DavidK "010" works to your example. But, your point is still a problem I didn't think of - setting A to "1" and B to "0" is a problem. I edited the post to remedy this.

Comment: I think I misread your original formulation, and therefore misidentified the counterexamples; but you seem to have identified and fixed them, so all's well.

Answer (score 0):

For finite strings, the lexicographic order will do if you tinker with it a bit so that one (or more) of the letters of the alphabet sorts before the empty string.

In more detail, say you have a two-letter alphabet $\Sigma=\{+,-\}$. Given two different strings $X,Y\in\Sigma^{<\omega}$, where without loss of generality $Y$ is not an initial substring of $X$ (otherwise we can swap them): if $a$ is the first letter of $Y$ following the largest common initial substring of $X$ and $Y$, put $X<Y$ if $a=+$, and $X>Y$ if $a=-$.

This gives a dense linear order: given $X<Z$, we have $X<X+<Z$ or $X<Z-<Z$.

In the case of a general alphabet $\Sigma$ with a fixed order $\prec$ on the letters $a\in\Sigma$, split the alphabet in two disjoint nonempty sets $\Sigma=\Sigma^-\cup\Sigma^+$ so that $\Sigma^+$ is closed upwards in $\prec$, and put
\begin{align*}
XaY&<XbZ&&\text{if }a\prec b,\\
X&<XaY&&\text{if }a\in\Sigma^+,\\
XaY&<X&&\text{if }a\in\Sigma^-
\end{align*}
for all strings $X,Y,Z$ and letters $a,b$. Note that the only difference from the standard lexicographic order is in the third clause.

Another way to view it is that you consider finite strings as extended on the right-hand side to infinite strings using a special symbol $\epsilon\notin\Sigma$, and you order them according to the lexicographic order of the infinite extensions, with respect to some ordering $\prec$ of $\Sigma\cup\{\epsilon\}$. If you make $\epsilon$ smaller than all actual letters $a\in\Sigma$, you get the usual lexicographic order on finite strings, whereas if there are $a,b\in\Sigma$ such that $a\prec\epsilon\prec b$, you get a dense order.

Comment: Another neat possibility is to use different orders on $\Sigma\cup\{\epsilon\}$ depending on the position, such as making $\epsilon$ alternately least and largest. This boils down to the following ordering: when $X,Y$ are not initial substrings of each other, we order them lexicographically in the usual way; when $X$ is an initial substring of $Y$, we put $X<Y$ if the length of $X$ is even, and $Y<X$ if it is odd.